# Taking the majority vote across matrix columns in R

Tags: r, matrix

```
mymat <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1
), .Dim = c(3L, 5L))

> mymat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1   -1   -1    1    1
[2,]    1   -1    1    1    1
[3,]    1   -1   -1    1   -1
```

I want to take the majority vote across the columns of `mymat`. In this example, the majority vote results across the 5 columns are: `1 -1 -1 1 1`.

I've tried looking at the solutions from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201765/majority-vote-in-r/17202024), but since the columns in `mymat` are unnamed, these solutions did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Mode` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode)

```
Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
 }
```

and use `apply` with `MARGIN` as 2 for columnwise application of the function

```
apply(mymat, 2, Mode)
#[1]  1 -1 -1  1  1
```

Or using `asplit/sapply`

```
sapply(asplit(mymat, 2), Mode)
```

NOTE: Both the solutions work on a general dataset and not just based on the values showed by the OP

```
mymat2 <- cbind(c('A', 'B', 'A'), c('e', 'e', 'f'))
sapply(asplit(mymat2, 2), Mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have binary voting of the type represented by your sample data you can use `sign()` and `colSums()`:

```
sign(colSums(mymat))
[1]  1 -1 -1  1  1
```